# Dynamic Choices query using multiple IDs Visual Workflow

Tags: visual-workflow

Is there a way to query records using multiple IDs in a Dynamic Choice? 
Dynamic Choice

[image: Dynamic Choice]

Basically what I'm trying to achieve here is: SELECT Sam_ID__c FROM Address_Information__c WHERE Id in: "(List of Sam_IDS)"

Is there a way to achieve this on Dynamic Choices?

Cheers,

Comment: Unfortunately, Flow lacks certain functionalities we would all expect, this being one of them. In this case, by chance, isn't it a possibility to move the logic obtaining the set Id's to the criteria inside the dynamic choice?

Comment: Apologies, but what do you mean by "the criteria inside the dynamic choice?". Isn't the dynamic choice criteria already the one in my screenshot?

Comment: Yes, they are indeed in your screenshot. I figure there is a small chance that those criteria (and the limited logic provided) are able to help you out, but it would be pretty terrific if it was.

Comment: I just ran into this same issue. I submitted an idea for it: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000LmlBQAS